# Zoom into picture

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this picture which I want to display into JavaFX application.

[image]

I tested to use `setFitHeight` and `setFitWidth` but the image is shrink. I want to zoom the original picture and display only the center of the image keeping the original size. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a [viewport](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#setViewport%28javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D%29) in an ImageView.